# Deleted origin branches. Need to restore them

Tags: git, asp.net-core, branch

I was using branches for this exercise project and thought I should delete branches after I'm done. However I well prepared for what to delete and how and now I'm in a pickle. I found SO questions about restoring deleted branches, however I ran into another problem. I removed the appsettings file from my worktree and as can be seen from the two screenshots below, when I try to pull, it says I don't have any local changes and when I use **git checkout**, it says I do have local changes to the appsettings file. Keep in mind, I made the changes not from my local repo first, but from the remote one. I'm not sure why. I wanted to remove the sensitive information as soon as possible.

[first](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vOESS.jpg)

[second](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uGGk7.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you use `git pull / stash` in wrong way:

1. To **commit** something, you should **add** it to commit: `git add some-file && git commit`
2. Before **stashing**, you should better to **add** files
3. Finally, check `git status` before **pulling**, it shouldn't have any changes.